# Unable to find type [cultureinfo]

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have powershell v2. I am getting below error.

```
Unable to find type [cultureinfo]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
```

Can anybody encounter this error before? My script is working fine on powershell v3 but in my server its PS v2 and i can't upgrade it.

This is the command which i am running.

```
$log_date = [datetime]::ParseExact('Tue Aug  4 17:05:41 2015','ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy',[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture,'AllowInnerWhite')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only a few namespaces are included in PowerShell's search for type names (and the list expands from version to version).

And [`System.Globalization`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Globalization.aspx) (which contains [`CultureInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx)) is not one.

But the resolution of names is relative to those namespaces that PowerShell defaults, so you can use `[Globalization.CultureInfo]`.

Comment: Can you please show me an example. I never used cultureinfo.

Comment: $log_date = [datetime]::ParseExact('Tue Aug  4 17:05:41 2015','ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy',[globalization.cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture,'AllowInnerWhite') is it fine?

Comment: @404 Yes that's what you need (just a matter of giving enough information for PSH to find the type.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Small things but big impact